# How can I customize the commit command in subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, aptana, subclipse, aptana3

I can connect to my subversion server fine with Subclipse, but my commit is not working, and I'd like to add in some custom commands to make it work (I need to pass a un/pw). How can I set these parameters?

Right now the command it's setting is just 
      `commit -m ""`
I'd like it to be

`commit -m --username <un> --password <pw>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion will prompt you for username/password unless it has cached valid credentials.  If you do not want to use those credentials, then you need to clear Subversion's cache.  If using JavaHL, that means deleting the ~/.subversion/auth folder.  On Windows, that is %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth

SVNKit caches credentials in the Eclipse keyring file.

Comment: It seems I'm not getting prompted for credentials to view the SVN contents, only to commit. Anyway I can force it to send credentials ?

Comment: It is not possible to force a SVN client to send credentials.  The SVN server challenges for credentials and only then does the client send them.  Change your server to not allow anonymous access and you will be challenged.  See the note near the end of these docs:  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds